# Importing from sub-folder hierarchy in python

Tags: python, import, python-2.7, subdirectory

i am trying to import specified modules from test_file hierarchy

something like :

```
test_case1.py
test_subsuite_2
test_sub_2.1.1.py
test_suite2
```

is it possible to do a run import on this hierarchy

```
/project/main.py
/project/test_files
```

test_files folder hierarchy is like this :

```
test_files
    test_suite1
        test_case1.py
        test_subsuite_1
            test_sub1_1.py
            test_sub1_2.py
        test_subsuite_2
            test_subsuite_2_1
                test_sub_2.1.1.py
            test_sub2_1.py
            test_sub3_2.py

    test_suite2
        test_case2.py
        test_subsuite2_1
            test_sub21_1.py
            test_sub21_2.py
        test_subsuite2_2
            test_sub22_1.py
            test_sub23_2.py
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an empty file called `__init__.py` in all you folders. Then you can import using `.` as a folder separator. [Documentation here.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Comment: For me, this still gives `ImportError: No module named...`

Answer (score 5):

The key is to create a blank file `__init__.py` on *all* subfolders containing the files you want to import. 
In your case, you will have to create the `__init__.py` files on all of the following folders-

- test_files
- test_files\test_suite1
- test_files\test_suite1\test_subsuite_2
- test_files\test_suite1\test_subsuite_2\test_subsuite_2_1

Also, when you import files be careful about specifying the import path correctly, with the entire path from the topmost level specified, and with different folder levels separated by a `.`
For example, you must import test_case1 by specifying :

`from test_files.test_suite1 import test_case1`

Similarly, `test_subsuite_2` can be imported by specifying :

`from test_files.test_suite1 import test_subsuite_2`